# How to provide two separate auth service with angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm working with angular 7 and firebase recently I had a problem with AngularFireAuth,
in my application I have two login service one for the client and the other for an administrator I finishing the admin authentication but when I generate a new auth service for my client somehow is linked to the admin for example when I log out from the admin interface its logged out from the client interface too also when the admin logged in the client logged in too with the admin id this is the problem I tried to fix with generating two services in angular one for the admin and one for the client but its the same they are linked to the same auth service.

Comment: Why there is two auth service.?!

Comment: One for the the admin and one for the client if you have another solution please i would love to hear it

Comment: What is your exact requirement.?

Comment: I have two Admin and client and both of them they need to login with firebase in the same application